# Reading XML Attributes in Loop

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have problem with reading xml atributes in for-next loop, atributes have numbers 1,2,3
how resolve it?

example xml :

```
<nr1>0 445 110 002</nr1> 
<make1>FIAT</make1>
<type1>CRI-1.0 </type1>
<model1>DUCATO 2.2 </model1>

<nr2>0 445 110 007</nr2>
<make2>PSA FIAT</make2>
<type2>CRI-1.0 </type2>
<model2>SCUDO 2.0JTD </model2>

<nr3>0 445 110 007</nr3>
<make3>PSA FIAT</make3>
<type3>CRI-1.0 </type3>
<model3>SCUDO 2.0JTD </model3>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx) on element name:

```
Class Car
  Public nr As String
  Public make As String
  Public type As String
  Public model As String
End Class

Sub Main()
  Dim cars = <cars>
               <nr1>0 445 110 002</nr1>
               <make1>FIAT</make1>
               <type1>CRI-1.0 </type1>
               <model1>DUCATO 2.2 </model1>

               <nr2>0 445 110 007</nr2>
               <make2>PSA FIAT</make2>
               <type2>CRI-1.0 </type2>
               <model2>SCUDO 2.0JTD </model2>

               <nr3>0 445 110 007</nr3>
               <make3>PSA FIAT</make3>
               <type3>CRI-1.0 </type3>
               <model3>SCUDO 2.0JTD </model3>
             </cars>

  Dim carsList As New List(Of Car)
  Dim newCar As New Car
  For Each el As XElement In cars.Elements
    If el.Name.ToString.StartsWith("nr") Then
      If newCar.nr IsNot Nothing Then
        carsList.Add(newCar)
        newCar = New Car
      End If
      newCar.nr = el.Value.ToString
    End If
    If el.Name.ToString.StartsWith("make") Then _
      newCar.make = el.Value.ToString
    If el.Name.ToString.StartsWith("type") Then _
      newCar.type = el.Value.ToString
    If el.Name.ToString.StartsWith("model") Then _
      newCar.model = el.Value.ToString
  Next
  carsList.Add(newCar)
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Display all car numbers in one line via comma.

With LINQ:

```
Dim carNumbersOnly As String =
  String.Join(", ", carsList.Select(Function(car) car.nr))
```

Without LINQ:

```
Private Function CarsToString(cars As IEnumerable(Of Car)) As String
  Dim numbersList As New List(Of String)
  For Each c As Car In cars
    numbersList.Add(c.nr)
  Next
  Return String.Join(", ", numbersList)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim carNumbersOnly As String = CarsToString(carsList)
```

You can assign to `TextBox.Text` instead of a string, the above is for demo purposes only.

Comment: Thanks for help,but this code generates errors in below lines

Dim cars = < cars> ... 

and
Dim carsList As New List(Of Car)
Dim newCar As New Car

Comment: @user3449603: It runs fine for me. `carsList` gets populated with 3 car objects. Which visual studio are you using? Mine is 2013. Which error are you getting?

Comment: I use VS2008,firstly I can't dim cars = <cars>  <nr1>0 445 110 002</nr1> etc... it generate errors, I think should be dim cars as ...,or I don't understad it_________also Dim carsList As New List(Of Car) generate error : "type car is not defined"

Comment: I made test and if I opened new project in VS2008 , then it works without errors (after little modification), but in existing project this generate many errors (when I paste sub main()...)

Comment: @user3449603: It *is* VB.NET 10 syntax. For big chunks of code, be sure that I wrote in VS first, and verified not only for compile time errors, but also that it runs perfectly and yields expected results. VS 2008 uses version 9, I don't remember if such inline xml assignment was supported in it. Option infer On allows you to skip explicit type declaration. So `Dim a = 5` is a perfectly valid statement, `a` will be of type integer. `XDocument/XElement` is supported since .NET 3.5. Try doing [load from file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @user3449603: As a side note, when you say `generates many errors`, it does not help me help you. Always specify line number (or just paste a line as is), and the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: @user3449603: You are probably missing references or imported namespaces. Check this out - this is default setup for new projects in VS 2013 - http://postimg.org/image/5ouccy6mv/ You should have XML LINQ. Otherwise it does not know about XElement.

Comment: but tell me ,how display carsList in textbox, because carsList can't be converted to string.

Comment: @user3449603: How would you like to display them? Please give a screenshot, mockup, drawing or similar.

Comment: now I want see it in textbox only all numbers :0 445 110 002, 0 445 110 007 etc.

Comment: @user3449603: You can do it like this: `TextBox1.Text = String.Join(", ", carsList.Select(Function(car) car.nr))`.

Comment: I'm beginer and I don;t understand this line:) if I use  nr="1" then textbox is empty

Comment: @user3449603: First make it work by pasting into your code, and run through with debugger, make sure `Text` property is assigned as expected. `String.Join` joins a list of string variables via a separator, `", "` in this case. A list of string variables is selected using LINQ to objects and its `Select` method, via lambda/inline function, which selects `nr` from every `car` object, thereby forming an `IEnumerable(Of String)`, which can be passed to `String.Join`. If it's still too complicated, I can rewrite using a regular loop and no LINQ. Please let me know.

Comment: yes, please without LINQ, but this is to hard for me.

Comment: line  Return String.Join(", ", numbersList) generate error with numbersList:'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String'

Comment: @user3449603: Weird, it worked for me just fine. Try `String.Join(", ", numbersList.ToArray)`.

Comment: then is without error, but line "End function" is underlined , maybe needed is any  "return" ?

Comment: @user3449603: Yes, `Return String.Join(", ", numbersList.ToArray)`.

Comment: yes, now is ok, but I don't know which string (or how) I should display in testbox :)

Comment: @user3449603: Like I said, you can do `TextBox1.Text = CarsToString(carsList)`, assuming your TextBox is named `TextBox1`. If it's named differently, please change accordingly.

Comment: yes I have txtbox1 ,still displayed is empty textbox if I have TextBox1.Text = CarsToString(carsList)

Comment: @user3449603: Then maybe your `carsList` is empty?

Comment: yes is empty:), because probably I don't know how choose "nr", or how to fill carlist...

Comment: @user3449603: I am assuming your XML is stored in a file. In this case, you can use [XDocument.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load(v=vs.110).aspx). You may need to adjust your loop, if the structure is different from what I wrote above.

Comment: I don't understand,In your listing I have to load data from string "cars" or from file on disk ? I just want extract data from string "cars" which include xml. Now I use string "cars" and I have empty textbox, because I don't see where is choosed number 1,2,3 of "nr1","nr2","nr3"

Comment: @user3449603: Then use `XDocument.Parse(yourCarsStringThatContainsXML)`

Comment: yes but what next ? can you edit your main listing ?

Comment: is no simpler method for extract data form my xml file without <cars>...</cars> ? only in loop search for example x=1,node "nr" & x ,then software search "nr1" and extract  "0 445 110 002"

Comment: @user3449603: Rest is the same. Only replace initialization, i.e. `Dim cars = <xml>` with `Dim cars = XDocument.Parse(...)`. What I suggested is a proven approach, that works. There is a more simple method, like doing string search, but it will not always work. Better stick to the standard.

Comment: now I changed to XDocument.Parse(str2) str2 this is string readed from file and I received error in line  For Each el As XElement In cars.Elements , because I don't have "car", I have str2, how it resolve ?

Comment: @user3449603: Please update your question with the code you currently have, and describe what's wrong with it in as much detail as possible.